# QueryBuilder on a non object

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation

I want create a multilingual web site, and for that I use Symfony with the `PrezentBundle` and `A2lixBundle`. I would get the list of my data by locale with entity repo.

I have this error :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: __clone method called on non-object in /project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php line 238
```

Here is my repo :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin('c.criteres', 'crit')
        ->leftjoin('c.translations', 'ct', 'WITH', 'ct.locale = :locale')
        ->setParameters('locale', 'fr');
var_dump($qb->getDql() );

return $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

The `var_dump` give me that :

```
SELECT c FROM NS\MyBundle\Entity\CritereCateg c LEFT JOIN c.criteres crit LEFT JOIN c.translations ct WITH ct.locale = :locale
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use Translatable doctrine extension in pair with jms/i18n-routing-bundle for i18n.

Comment: I have already make some test with StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle but with this I have another problem. ^^

Comment: I just want to say that translatable is really tested and stable extension, which works on a lot of sites... instead of bundles your're trying to implement.

Comment: You talking about Translatable in StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle or another bundle ?  Thanks for you answer. I found Prezent in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19430025/2543271 and he seem to say Gedmo is deprecated. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: Gemdo is not actively developed any more AFAIK. But you can use `DoctrineBehaviours` from [KnpLabs](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable).

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that about gedmo... it worked fine for me lately. On the other hand `PrezentBundle` is still beta AFAIK. Besides, last commints on github were 4-8 months ago. Anyway, this is already off-topic a bit :)

Comment: Thanks for the informations ! If I have too much problem with Prezent I'll change for KNPLabs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is probably because of misuse of the `setParameters()` mehtod. There is two simmilar methods for the doctrine query builder:

1) `setParameter()` which sets only one parameter per method usage. The syntax is:

```
// for numeric parameters
$qb->leftjoin('c.translations', 'ct', 'WITH', 'ct.locale = ?1')
   ->setParameter(1, 'fr');

// for string parameters
$qb->leftjoin('c.translations', 'ct', 'WITH', 'ct.locale = :locale')
   ->setParameter('locale', 'fr');
```

2) `setParameters()` which sets multiple parameters:

```
// String params
$qb->where('u.id = :uid')
   ->leftjoin('c.translations', 'ct', 'WITH', 'ct.locale = :locale')
   ->setParameters(array('locale' => 'fr', 'uid' => $userId));

// Numeric parameters are also available here
$qb->where('u.id = ?1')
   ->leftjoin('c.translations', 'ct', 'WITH', 'ct.locale = ?2')
   ->setParameters(array(2 => 'fr', 1 => $userId));
```

So you probably wanted to use `setParameter()` instead of `setParameters()` in your query builder.

Comment: So simple mistake... Thanks Hast!